# What are the differences between web-app Lastpass and KeePass, and how can I choose?

Tags: webapp-rec, passwords, lastpass

What are the main differences between these two tools, or other password management tools?

**What sort of questions could I ask myself to determine or rule out a possible solution?**

I am looking for something that:

- can be accessed through my iPhone, ideally with logging into websites
- can be accessed from a usb drive
- can store other data like financial information in
- can store multiple accounts for websites such as Gmail

Answers will be voted up by how much easier they make my choice between note apps.

I loved the way Senseful [answered another question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/what-are-the-differences-between-springpad-and-evernote-and-how-can-i-choose/4217#4217), where he stated the things that each of them do better.

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned in a LifeHacker post](http://lifehacker.com/5483119/the-easy-any+browser-any+os-password-solution) LastPass has a few advantages such as very good and supported browser extensions which make it great for websites. It is easier to use without configuration and the master password can be recovered.

That said while both work with the iPhone, with USB devices, can store other data, and can handle multiple accounts, if those are your main uses KeePass is probably superior. LastPass's USB key features are only available with its premium package whereas with KeePass is portable and you can easily store the data file or encryption key there. KeePass is more suited for storing non-web related passwords and is probably better with storing multiple accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to LastPass a couple of month ago. Then, the iPhone App of KeePass was only available in the US.

Comment: Sadly, the iPhone app has a really annoying bug; you can never finish entering a secure note.